# Maven doesn't compile and package with docker image on Spring, no goals specified

Tags: spring, docker, maven

I'm trying to compile an image using docker and maven, the Dockerfile is in the root of my Spring project, in the same directory as pom.xml
I have this in my DockerFile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17-slim AS BUILD
COPY src /app/src/
COPY pom.xml /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN mvn clean package
```

My pom is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ProyectoDiagrama</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProyectoDiagrama</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
  
  <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And when I run the image it throws:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.187 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-02T09:56:32Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

I think that writing `mvn clean package` I'm already defining the goal, so I don't know what to do.
If I use run as build in Spring, it works, but I need to do it in the Dockerfile.
Thanks on advance.

Comment: To clarify: when you are building it works, but when you are running the image with a `docker run` command, you get the error message?

Comment: @RickRackow I fixed It, it was because I used a bad commands to do It, trying of other way worked, thanks all the same

Comment: Please make sure to post what you did as an actual answer, so others can find it as well in the future

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I used:

```
FROM openjdk:21-ea-17-jdk-slim AS BUILD
# Establecemos el directorio de trabajo dentro del contenedor
WORKDIR /app
# Copiamos el proyecto de Spring a la imagen
COPY . /app
# Instalamos Maven
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y maven && \
    apt-get clean;
# Compilamos el proyecto y construimos el WAR
RUN mvn clean package
RUN mvn spring-boot:run
# Exponemos el puerto 8080 en la imagen
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: Consider explaining why it solves the problem, apart from just the code itselft.